# Why does `R` `glmnet` need to run with $\lambda$ in decreasing order?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, regularization, linear, glmnet

In `?glmnet::glmnet` documentation, it says

> Do not supply a single value for lambda (for predictions after CV use predict() instead). Supply instead a decreasing sequence of lambda values. glmnet relies on its warms starts for speed, and its often faster to fit a whole path than compute a single fit.

Why? What is the "warms starts" process? and why "fit a whole path than compute a single fit"? Does it have something to do with projected gradient descent?

Comment: The lasso estimate has a closed form (in particular, is zero) when $\lambda$ is large enough. Hence, it's the best place to start this warm start procedure. The convention--even when the first estimate isn't zero--follows from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Warm starts" is merely starting an optimization problem with values you suspect to be fairly close to the optimal solution. In the case of `glmnet`, it's pretty clear how to get warm starts; if ${\beta_{0.1}}$ is the solution you just solved for with $\lambda = 0.1$, and you want to find the solution when $\lambda = 0.09$...well $\beta_{0.1}$ seems like pretty good place to start.

It can also help to provide in descending order because $\beta_{0.1}$ should be closer to the zero vector than $\beta_{0.01}$, although I suspect the difference would be very minor to supply in ascending order.