# How to find the smallest $\lambda$ such that all Lasso / Elastic Net coefficients are zero?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, glmnet, elastic-net

In the documentation to R's glmnet package it states that when fitting an elastic net, the glmnet function will use a series of $\lambda$ values starting at the smallest $\lambda$ for which all coefficients are zero. How can I find such a value of $\lambda$?

Comment: are you asking how to find $\lambda$ mathematically or how to find it in `glmnet` model?

Comment: Mathematically.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166630/glmnet-compute-maximal-lambda-value

Answer (score 5):

A lasso solution $\widehat{\beta}(\lambda)$ solves 
$$\min_\beta \frac{1}{2}||y-X\beta||_2^2 +\lambda||\beta||_1.$$ 
and it is well known that we have  $\widehat{\beta}(\lambda)=0$ for all $\lambda \geq \lambda_1$ where $\lambda_1 = \max_j |X_j^Ty|$, which should give you the desired value.

Note that $\lambda_1$ may need a different scaling if the objective function is scaled differently.

---

Using the cars example with GLMNET:

`fit<-glmnet(as.matrix(mtcars[,-1]),mtcars[,1], intercept=FALSE, standardize=FALSE)
1/32*max(abs(t(as.matrix(mtcars[,-1]))%*%mtcars[,1]))/(head(fit$lambda))[1]`

This gives the value 1, as expected.

Note that standardize as well as intercept is set to FALSE. If standardize and intercept is set to TRUE, then the value of $\lambda$ is calculated on the scaled regressors.
(In this regards, take a look at https://think-lab.github.io/d/205/#5 for how to perform a proper scaling to get the results you want.):

`xy<-scale(mtcars)
fit<-glmnet(as.matrix(mtcars[,-1]),mtcars[,1])
(1/32*max(abs(t(xy[,-1])%*%mtcars[,1]*sqrt(32/31))))/(head(fit$lambda))[1]`

This once again gives the value 1...

*However I am not sure what glmnet is calculating if intercept = TRUE but standardize = FALSE.*

---

We saw that glmnet with its standard options calculates $\lambda_{1}$ as $$\lambda_{1} = \max_j| \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_j^*y|$$, where $x_j^* = \frac{x_j-\overline{x_j}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_j-\overline{x_j})^2}}.$

It turns out that for an elastic net problem (corresponding to $\alpha \in (0,1]$ in glmnet) its maximum value $\lambda_{1,\alpha}$ is calculated as

$$\lambda_{1,\alpha}= \lambda_{1}/\alpha$$.

Indeed, setting for example $\alpha=0.3$ we have:

`aa<-0.3
xy<-scale(mtcars)
fit<-glmnet(as.matrix(mtcars[,-1]),mtcars[,1],a=aa)
1/aa*(1/32*max(abs(t(xy[,-1])%*%mtcars[,1]*sqrt(32/31))))/(head(fit$lambda))[1]`

which results once again in an output value of $1$.

That's for the calculations. Note however that the elastic net criterion can be rewritten as a standard lasso problem.

Comment: we have: `(1/32*max(abs(t(xy[,-1])%*%xy[,1]*(sd(mtcars[,1])*sqrt(32/31)))))  ==  (1/32*max(abs(t(xy[,-1]*sqrt(32/31))%*%mtcars[,1]))))`
and can conclude that, standardize does only standardize the independent variables s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{ij}^2=n$ but the option doesn't touch the dependent variable.

Comment: The question seems to be asking about the case of elastic net. Perhaps it would be worthwhile to include the additional step of the derivation for finding this smallest $\lambda$ in the elastic net case, since this question would be a duplicate otherwise. Also, due to the scaling you use in the lasso definition, it seems like the result should actually be that $\lambda_1=2 \max_j |x_j^T y|$ for the lasso.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake - I adjusted the objective function by the term $\frac{1}{2}$ instead adjusting the $\lambda$.

Besides I added the calculations for the elastic net. Note, that $\alpha \to 0$  or $\alpha= 0$ is a special case (which would result in $\lambda = \infty$). Instead glmnet does its calculations for $\alpha = 0.001$. see its help-file.

Comment: "elastic net criterion can be rewritten as a standard lasso problem."  How?

Comment: You just have to augment your data - take a look at Lemma 1 of "Regularization and variable selection via the
elastic net" by Zou and Hastie for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that - would you happen to know also how this would extend to L0-penalized regression? I asked a question about that here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416144/minimum-and-maximum-regularization-in-l0-pseudonorm-penalized-regression

Answer (score 1):

First, I think `glmnet` will start with a large $\lambda$ instead of a small $\lambda$. Here is the documentation: note, if we want to specify $\lambda$, it is better in **decreasing order**.

> Typical usage is to have the program compute its own lambda sequence based on nlambda and lambda.min.ratio. Supplying a value of lambda overrides this. WARNING: use with care. Do not supply a single value for lambda (for predictions after CV use predict() instead). Supply instead a decreasing sequence of lambda values. glmnet relies on its warms starts for speed, and its often faster to fit a whole path than compute a single fit.

Also, See my question here: [Why does `R` `glmnet` need to run with $\lambda$ in decreasing order?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282263/why-does-r-glmnet-need-to-run-with-lambda-in-decreasing-order)

---

The fitting results contains the lambda value used. Here is an example.

```
library(glmnet)
fit=glmnet(as.matrix(mtcars[,-1]),mtcars[,1])
head(fit$lambda)
[1] 5.146981 4.689737 4.273114 3.893502 3.547614 3.232454
```